# How to avoid minification of JS files in linemanjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, linemanjs

Following is the lineman -
config file - http://pastebin.com/ZuNzDY8S
application file - http://pastebin.com/rSPdeSME

Now whenever I am running the command `lineman run` I am getting `app.js` | `vendor.js` | `plugin.js` js files into my generated folder as expected.

So in the index.html file I am getting -

```
  <script src="/js/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now few Files I do  not want to minify and merged into one, but the problem is can not refer the vendor files via -

```
<script src="vendor/plugin/myjsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which is also reasonable as the html is now in generated folder.

So what do I need to do in my config file to avoid few file compressions and how to reference those vendor files in my layout/template files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linemanjs` is using `grunt` tasks for the minification, to avoid this you can simply check the `application config` and comment it if you don't want it to happen.

FYI - I was not aware of grunt tasks at the time of question.

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem. I had to leave modernizr.js out of app.js . There is a special folder called "static". One under "app" and another one under "vendor". Everything you put there gets untouched. I just created a folder "vendor/static/js" and put modernizr.js there. In my page, just reference it as "js/modernizr.js".

I hope this helps you.
Guilherme (6qat).